# $X_n$ integrable r.v. decreasingly converges to $X$ almost surely. If $\inf_n\mathbb{E}X_n>-\infty$, show that $\mathbb{E}[X_n-X]\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{M},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and random variables $X_n \downarrow X$ almost surely. Each $X_n$ is integrable and $\inf_n \mathbb{E}[X_n] >-\infty$, prove that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X]$.

It is an exercise from *A Course in Probability Theory* by ChuangKailai (Page 75 Ex 18). It appears to be an application of Fatou's lemma in this version (replace $X_n-X$ by $f_n$):

If $f_n$ is a sequence of real-valued function **bounded by a non-negative integrable function** $g$ (i.e. $f_n<g$ a.e. and $\int gd\mathbb{P} <\infty$), we have
$$ \limsup_n \int f_n d\mathbb{P} \le \int\limsup_nf_nd\mathbb{P}$$

But it fails to work since only the integrals of $X_n$ are bounded, and the integrability of $X$ is unknown. I shall use the condition $\inf_n\mathbb{E}[X_n]>-\infty$ in a proper way. Any help will be highly approciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof is provided by my classmate, the **Levi monotone theorem** works here (I hardly use this theorem and the positive-negative division of a measurable function)：

**Levi theorem**:
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a non-negative increasing measurable function sequence, hence the almost everywhere limit $f = \lim f_n$ exists (can be infinite), we have
$$ \lim \int f_n = \int f $$

Rmk: It is the theorem of $a.e$ convergence implying $L^1$ convergence with the most simple condition.

We devide $X_n$ into $X_n^+=\chi\{X_n \ge 0\}X_n$ and $X_n^-=\chi\{X_n \le 0\}X_n$  ($X_n=X_n^+ - X_n^-$), then the integrability of $X_n$ gives the integrability of $X_n^+$ and $X_n^-$. Note that $X_n^+\downarrow X^+$ and $X_n^- \downarrow X^-$ and Levi theorem gives
$$ \lim \mathbb{E}[X_1^+ - X_n^+] = \mathbb{E}[X_1^+] - \mathbb{E}[X^+] $$
hence $X^+$ is integrable and $\lim \mathbb{E}[X_n^+]=\mathbb{E}[X^+]$

The estimation of $\mathbb{E}[X^-]$ uses the assumption $\inf_n \mathbb{E}[X_n] >-\infty$. Since $\mathbb{E}[X_n^+]$ is decreasing and bounded by $\mathbb{E}[X_1^+]$, one concludes $\inf_n\mathbb{E}[X_n^-] = \lim \mathbb{E}[X_n^-] > -\infty$. By Levi theorem again $\lim\mathbb{E}[X_n^-]=\mathbb{E}[X^-]$ and the RHS is finite by assumption, hence $X$ is integrable and the conclusion follows.